# simple jsonp store object is not displaying in child container tpl in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am developing demo app using sencha touch 2. I have list screen in which I am downloading data using jsonp and displaying list. Now on click of list row I am opening new details screen with passing current row store object.

In details screen I am able to get object and display it on main root container but the same value is not displaying from child container. Please refer my below code.

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.MyDetailView', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

xtype:'mydetailview',

requires:[

     'Ext.TitleBar',         
     'Ext.dataview.List',
     'Ext.XTemplate'
 ],

config: {

    // code snippet-1 ********* it is working *********

    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable:true,
    xtype: 'container',
    title:'Details',
    tpl: 'barname : {barname}',

    // ************** end **************

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Bar Info',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Back',
                    id: 'btnBack'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    align: 'right',
                    text: 'Edit Beers'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'map',
                    height: 80,
                    margin: '10',
                    width: 80
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,

                    layout: {
                        align: 'center',
                        pack: 'center',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {

                            // code snippet-2 ********* it is NOT working *********

                            xtype: 'container',
                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                            tpl: 'barname : {barname}',      
                            //html: '<div>barname : {barname}</div>',
                            margin: '10 10 10 0',
                            width: '100%'

                            // ************** end **************
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

In above code "code snippet-1" is working while the same code is not working in inner container tpl "code snippet-2". Please guide me what is the wrong with my code. How can I use "barname" in inner container. I have also tried with html also in place of tpl, which is also not working.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you post the code where you pass the data to next view and where it is being assinged to parent and child view?

Comment: You may need to pass in your JsonP data to the `data` config for your child container inorder to use the `tpl` config.

Comment: Hi cclerville, can you give me code as i am new in sencha so don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Hi phazorRise, I am using below code to pass store object as data and displaying it in a view using above original post code. I have using below code in onListItemTap in controller. 'var view = this.getMyDetailView() ? this.getMyDetailView() : Ext.create('Demo.view.MyDetailView');
   view.setData(record.data);
   Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(view);'